# no usbJava in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, libusb

I got a .jar file from a code that works on Windows, and I'm trying to run it on Linux, but I keep getting this message, and don't know what to do.

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no usbJava in java.library.path
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1856)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
            at ch.ntb.usb.LibusbJava.<clinit>(LibusbJava.java:366)
            at ch.ntb.usb.USB.init(USB.java:315)
            at ch.ntb.usb.USB.getBus(USB.java:296)
            at ch.ntb.usb.Device.initDevice(Device.java:102)
            at ch.ntb.usb.Device.open(Device.java:222)
            at TransmitterModuleHIDInterface.run(TransmitterModuleHIDInterface.java:28)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm using the Java wrapper for the libusb-0.1 (I followed the installation instructions [here](http://libusbjava.sourceforge.net/wp/?page_id=8)).

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a link to the shared library, as per the Linux installation instructions:

http://libusbjava.sourceforge.net/wp/?page_id=8

If you're having trouble building the shared library this might be of some help:

http://me.opengroove.org/2010/01/libusbjavaso.html

The sources for the library itself is under /libusbjava/trunk/LibusbJava/ in the SVN source tree.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the problem. I managed to build the library, and I used `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"))` to make sure that there was a link to it on java.library.path